# unrar.exe and | pipe on windows

Tags: windows, stdout, pipe, stdin, rar

I just downloaded the freeware unrar.exe from winrar website. If, from the command line, you tipe

```
unrar.exe p -inul myarchive.rar
```

It "prints" out to default std the content of my archive. Since the archive is just one .avi file, if I do:

```
unrar.exe p -inul myarchive.rar > output.avi
```

It works perfectly. Now, I'd need to redirect the output std of this program to the input std on a program of mine. This means that I do:

```
unrar.exe p -inul myarchive.rar | myprogram.exe
```

myprogram.exe is just a simple c file that every second (this means: very slowly) reads a char from standard input and prints it to screen. 
After approximately 10000 chars, I get only the -1 byte (FF in hexadecimal representation).

Why this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: EOF? it's defined as -1 in stdio.h. How do you get the char? getchar()?

Comment: getchar, exactly! Quite strange... since both the .rar file and the .avi file are longer than 700MB. It started printing out -1 approx. at byte 10000!

Comment: my guess is that the pipe is overflown, 700MB is just too big to be passed in memory. try using temporary files instead.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to do the job using temporary files!